# Javascript Crossbrowser

Tags: javascript, events, internet-explorer-7

I made a script to color rows of tables. My script only works in Internet Explorer 8 or higher. How do I make my script crossbrowser?

```
window.onload = (function()
{
    "use strict";
    var c = 0, i, j, t = document.getElementsByTagName("tbody"), r;
    for(i = 0; i < t.length; i++)
    {
        r = t[i].getElementsByTagName("tr");
        for(j = 0; j < r.length; j++)
        {
            if(c%2 === 1)
            {
                r[j].setAttribute("class", "colored");
            }
            c++;
        }
        c = 0;
    }
});
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working in which other browser(s) with what error message(s)?

Comment: Are you using jQuery or some other library?

Comment: I modified the code, removed the jQuery.
My script does not add the class to the elements colored "tr" in Internet Explorer 7.
In my css I have. Colored td {background-color: # F9F9F9;}, so that the necessary element "tr" to get colored class.

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
r[j].setAttribute("class", "colorful");
```

to

```
r[j].className = "colorful";
```

IE has a history of getting `setAttribute` wrong, and one of the ways in which it gets it wrong relates to the `class` attribute. (In earlier versions, even though the attribute is called `class`, they want you to call it `className` even when using `setAttribute`, which is just completely wrong. Other browsers, and more recent versions of IE, get it right.)

Fortunately, the `class` attribute is reliably reflected as a *property* on the element called `className` (in all browsers), so you can side-step IE's `setAttribute` issues by going to the reflected property instead as shown above.

(The same thing happens with the `for` attribute on `label` elements, FYI; use the `htmlFor` reflected property instead.)

Comment: Thank you!
That was what was missing.